# How to attach a media files from gallery in whatsapp?

Tags: whatsapp

In WhatsApp, I am able to attach pictures from the gallery in WP8 but not audio/video files. Only recorded audio/video can get attached.

Could you please suggest when the upgrade will come for this since its a major drawback in WP8 WhatsApp now?

Answer (score 2):

we can attach video and audio and every thing by whatsapp. now listen carefully, i have lumia 625 in which(or any lumia of w8) go into the whatsapp and choose any contact to which you want to send a video ,then at bottom click on  album and choose any video and picture.

Comment: I understood the security behind the design, but if you see its not stealing, for sharing the files to your friends is the main use of WhatsApp apart from text. Every time its not possible to record and send the audios, if we need to share song with friends, we can't. Hence its a drawback only. If sharing media files from gallery and save option for received audio/video is enhanced in next update, using the App will be more efficient.

Comment: Yes, but once you share a video with someone, they can distribute it like any other video. For instance, if you share a downloaded (and paid for) song with someone over Whatsapp, they can in turn distribute it with anyone they like. Blocking this isn't foolproof but it is part of the bigger picture.

Comment: Whatsapp 2.11.298 for wp8 is unable to attach pre recorded video's and when you click share at a video, you cannot send it to whatsapp... also you cannot search the web for images to send with whatsapp. this feature is only build in for changing the image of a group, not in a conversation unfortunately.